# Data aggregation with left-outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, outer-join

I am trying to pull some data with transaction counts, by branch, by week, which will later be used to feed some dynamic .Net charts.

I have a calendar table, I have a branch table and I have a transaction table.

Here is my DB info (only relevant columns included):

Branch Table:

```
ID (int), Branch (varchar)
```

Calendar Table:

```
Date (datetime), WeekOfYear(int)
```

Transaction Table:

```
Date (datetime), Branch (int), TransactionCount(int)
```

So, I want to do something like the following:

```
Select b.Branch, c.WeekOfYear, sum(TransactionCount)
FROM BranchTable b
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionTable t
    on t.Branch = b.ID
JOIN Calendar c
    on t.Date = c.Date
WHERE YEAR(c.Date) = @Year // (SP accepts this parameter)
GROUP BY b.Branch, c.WeekOfYear
```

Now, this works **EXCEPT** when a branch doesn't have any transactions for a week, in which case **NO RECORD** is returned for that branch on that week.  What I **WANT** is to get that branch, that week and "0" for the sum.  I tried isnull(sum(TransactionCount), 0) - but that didn't work, either.  So I will get the following (making up sums for illustration purposes):

```
+--------+------------+-----+
| Branch | WeekOfYear | Sum |
+--------+------------+-----+
|      1 |          1 |  25 |
|      2 |          1 |  37 |
|      3 |          1 |  19 |
|      4 |          1 |   0 |  //THIS RECORD DOES NOT GET RETURNED, BUT I NEED IT!
|      1 |          2 |  64 |
|      2 |          2 |  34 |
|      3 |          2 |  53 |
|      4 |          2 |  11 |
+--------+------------+-----+
```

So, why doesn't the left-outer join work?  Isn't that supposed to

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

**EDIT: SAMPLE TABLE DATA:**

`Branch` Table:

```
+----+---------------+
| ID |    Branch     |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | First Branch  |
|  2 | Second Branch |
|  3 | Third Branch  |
|  4 | Fourth Branch |
+----+---------------+
```

`Calendar` Table:

```
+------------+------------+
|    Date    | WeekOfYear |
+------------+------------+
| 01/01/2015 |          1 |
| 01/02/2015 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

`Transaction` Table

```
+------------+--------+--------------+
|    Date    | Branch | Transactions |
+------------+--------+--------------+
| 01/01/2015 |      1 |           12 |
| 01/01/2015 |      1 |            9 |
| 01/01/2015 |      2 |            4 |
| 01/01/2015 |      2 |            2 |
| 01/01/2015 |      2 |           23 |
| 01/01/2015 |      3 |           42 |
| 01/01/2015 |      3 |           19 |
| 01/01/2015 |      3 |            7 |
+------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Change `JOIN Calendar c` to `LEFT JOIN Calendar c` too.

Comment: You need to create a complete list of each branch and week, then left join that to the transactions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that - the branch table and calendar table don't have any columns on which to join

Comment: @Darka - I tried that, but got the same results.

Comment: Can you edit your post with some sample data from each table?

Comment: Branch Table has Branch = 4?

Comment: Sorry, @Darka - I don't understand your question.

Comment: Why in God's name was this down-voted?!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring in the Calendar *before* you bring in the transactions:

```
SELECT b.Branch, c.WeekOfYear, sum(TransactionCount)
FROM BranchTable b 
INNER JOIN CalendarTable c ON YEAR(c.Date) = @Year
LEFT JOIN TransactionTable t ON t.Branch = b.ID AND t.Date = c.Date
GROUP BY b.Branch, c.WeekOfYear
ORDER BY c.WeekOfYear, b.Branch
```

Comment: I will test this out.  I won't be back at work until next week, but I'll be sure to revisit this page and accept your answer if this works.

Comment: This works great!  Only change I had to make was isnull(sum(TransactionCount), 0)

Comment: You've got a syntax error in this query. It will throw an error on the ORDER BY.

Comment: how this works you cannot use `B.id` in `order by`. It will throw `B.id is invalid in the ORDER BY...` Btw not my **DV**

Comment: Depends on your database engine. Sql Server is perfectly happy to use a table alias in an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn SQL Server will throw an error because you are using `b.id` in the order by clause but it's not included in the `GROUP BY` or aggregate - see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/318b3/5

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I had meant to use b.Branch. The answer is right now.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to return a query that contains each Branch and each week, then you'll need to first create a full list of that, then use a LEFT JOIN to the transactions to get the count.  The code will be similar to:

```
select bc.Branch, 
   bc.WeekOfYear, 
   TotalTransaction = coalesce(sum(t.TransactionCount), 0)
from
(
  select b.id, b.branch, c.WeekOfYear, c.date
  from branch b
  cross join Calendar c
  -- if you want to limit the number of rows returned use a WHERE to limit the weeks
  -- so far in the year or using the date column
  WHERE c.date <= getdate()
   and YEAR(c.Date) = @Year // (SP accepts this parameter)
) bc
left join TransactionTable t
  on t.Date = bc.Date
  and bc.id = t.branch
GROUP BY bc.Branch, bc.WeekOfYear
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/721d1/5)

This code will create in your subquery a full list of each branch with each date. Once you have this list, then you can JOIN to the transactions to get your total transaction count and you'd return each date as you want.

Comment: I was thinking CROSS JOIN at first, too, but he does want to limit which calendar records he sees, so an INNER JOIN with the WHERE clause as the join condition seemed more appropriate.

Comment: I thought this looked close, at first, but this query returns 265 records when I want 12 (4 branches, 3 weeks so far for 2015)

Comment: @Stan You can limit the number of calendar dates by using a where clause on the subquery - if you only need the first few weeks of the year then include `where weekofyear < 4` or filter on the `c.date` column comparing it to `getdate()` -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/318b3/7

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The INNER JOIN is performing the same function as the CROSS JOIN because you aren't joining the `branch` table to the `calendar` table on a specific column - see this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/318b3/8 - They need to use an additional filter like my edit to limit the # of rows for the year so far or to filter for certain weeks.

Comment: Guys, check out Joel's answer.  It's exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Stan Just to clarify that answer performs the same functionality as this does.  Since that version is not joining the `branch` table to any specific column in `calendar` it is essentially performing a cross join.  If you are returning additional rows, then you'd need to filter the data similar to what I showed in my edit.

Comment: @bluefeet - Sorry, I just saw the edit.  Thank you again for your help - I upvoted this, but I can't accept more than one answer, unfortunately.

Comment: +2 for the `cross join`.